# Not able to update Bundler version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler

I have a gemfile.lock which requires Bundle 2.2.19 . My system has Bundle 1.11.2. Now I ran the following commands:

```
gem update --system
sudo gem install bundler
```

Has the following output:

```
Successfully installed bundler-2.2.31.gem
```

But after that, I do:

```
Bundler --version
```

I still get

```
Bundler version 1.11.2
```

And if I try to do

```
bundle install
```

I get

```
You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lock file
```

I also tried running

```
bundler update --bundler
```

But that does not work either. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling but while uninstalling, it only uninstalls the 2.2.31 version. Also tried something like

```
bundle _2.2.31_ install
```

But it says could not find command. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Which ruby version are  you using?, also dthe instruction is "bundle update --bundler" 
first bundle without r

Comment: That does not work either. Ruby version  is 2.3.1p112

Comment: Try `gem install bundler` without `sudo`

Comment: Without sudo, it gives error because it doesn't have permission to write to the folders.